# JavaScript function can't be identified from an onchange

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i get a error below:

```
05-31 11:17:20.427: D/CordovaLog(20889): Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

on my html i have embeded the following to pass the toggleswitch element to my javascript function

```
 <select name="toggleswitch1" id="toggleswitch1" data-theme="" data-role="slider"
            data-mini="true" onchange="hello(document.getElementById('toggleswitch1'))">
```

here is my javascript

```
<script>
        function hello(toggle)
        {
        var e = toggle;
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if value == "yes"
            {
                //do something
            }

        }
  </script>
```

what am i missing?

Comment: In the console you should also see something like `SyntaxError: missing ( before condition`. The function is not defined because your JavaScript is invalid.

Comment: the script is embeded in the <head> tag on my index.html. the function works if i remove the param arguments and just call hello();

Comment: try this once, change `hello(document.getElementById('toggleswitch1'))` to `hello(this);`

Comment: How can it work if it is syntactically invalid? Whether you pass arguments to the function or not does not have any impact on whether the function can be found or not.

Comment: @Satpal: While using `this` is certainly better, this has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Works fine when the error is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/h8r6L/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your script :

```
  <script>
    function hello(toggle)
    {
    var e = toggle;
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (value == "yes")
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: @Miro: You defined the function inside the `load` event handler. It is not global and cannot be found. You have to include the code directly in the `head` or the `body`.

Comment: Thanks. that fixed my issue. still new to javascript! What is the best javascript/html5 editor that can highlight such syntax errors?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<script>
    function hello(toggle)
    {
    var e = toggle;
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(value == "yes")
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
</script>
```

You forgot the `(` and `)` on the if:

[image: Diff]